# Escape "%" symbol when calling CString::FormatV

Tags: c++, mfc, escaping, variadic-functions, cstring

I'm using var args in a file i/o function. It works fine unless the string which is wanting to be outputted contains a `%` and there are no additional arguments. E.g. the string `<name px=100% />` would cause the issue, as an example. The code is roughly as follows:

```
void OutV(CString s, va_list args)
{
    CString formatted;
    formatted.FormatV(str, args);

    // Do stuff with formatted....
}
```

Is there a way that I could make it so that having a `%` symbol does not cause a problem. Ideally I'd like it inside of the `OutV` function above so that it only has to be in one place.

I can't do a simple replace all % with %% as then if there is a %d in there then that still needs to be substituted as an integer.

Comment: I can't do a simple replace all % with %% as then if there is a `%d` in there then that still needs to be substituted.

Comment: So how do you differentiate the 2 `%` in '%d%dummyName' ?

Comment: I have modified my answer a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your literal format strings escape the percent sign by doubling it: `%%`.

You might also want to consider using something like

```
OutV(CString("%s"), "<name px=100% />");
```

#### UPDATE

> I can't do a simple replace all % with %% as then if there is a %d in there then that still needs to be substituted.

You need to piece things together more carefully. e.g.,

```
OutV(CString("%s%d%s"), "<name px=", 100, "% />");
```

Comment: I've edited the OP: "I can't do a simple replace all % with %% as then if there is a %d in there then that still needs to be substituted"